# How to select record last update in grouping sql db2

Tags: sql, grouping, db2-400

I have the following table:

Table 1

```
ITEM_NAME|ID_ITEM|SUBMIT_DATE|DELIVERY_DATE
SUGAR    |11111  |2017-02-15|2017-02-18 01:00:21
SU GAR   |11111  |2019-03-17|2019-03-18 05:04:06
PIE      |22222  |2015-02-25|2015-04-23 12:12:00
PIE SWEET|22222  |2015-01-30|2016-02-01 14:21:11
SWEET    |22222  |2018-05-18|2018-05-19 18:14:01
CANDY    |33333  |2018-05-04|2018-08-21 13:04:02
CANCAN   |33333  |2014-01-05|2014-02-12 02:05:23
CANDYDY  |33333  |2019-07-04|2019-07-08 12:10:02
CANDY    |33333  |2017-09-27|2017-09-28 14:02:03
CANDY CAN|33333  |2016-09-24|2016-09-25 01:23:20
SNACK    |44444  |2018-12-30|2018-12-31 10:02:05
```

Table 2

`ID_SUPPLY|ID_ITEM|SUBMIT_DATE
FF3355656|11111|2017-02-15 01:02:03
G88889898|11111|2019-03-17 21:12:21
HH555|22222|2015-01-30 10:25:10
I8990909|22222|2018-05-18 14:25:10
J98900|44444|2018-12-30 25:10:14
L89800|33333|2014-01-05 14:08:14
M9890890980-|33333|2019-07-04 13:05:06`

I want to achieve the result which selects all field on TABLE1 and ID_SUPPLY FORM Table2 and have table1.SUBMIT_DATE DESC and table1.DELIVERY_DATE DESC and table2.SUBMIT_DATE DESC per ID_ITEM. Ie

`ID_SUPPLY|ITEM_NAME|ID_ITEM|SUBMIT_DATE|DELIVERY_DATE
G88889898|SU GAR|11111|2019-03-17|2019-03-18 05:04:06
I8990909|SWEET |22222|2018-05-18|2018-05-19 18:14:01
M9890890980-|CANDYDY|33333|2019-07-04|2019-07-08 12:10:02
J98900|SNACK|44444|2018-12-30|2018-12-31 10:02:05`

Can someone help with the query? Thank you before.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_item order by submit_date desc, delivery_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: thank you @gordon linoff, if I use a join table where should I put the table alias t?

Comment: @mae . . . It depends.  Probably the simplest method is to define your current query as a CTE.

Comment: I have 2 tables namely table 1 and table 2, as above. can you help me?

Comment: i get error like this: Column or global variable SEQNUM not found. Cause . . . . . :   SEQNUM was not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not found as a global variable in *N. If the table is *N, SEQNUM is not a column of any table or view that can be referenced

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename a
where SUBMIT_DATE in (select max(SUBMIT_DATE) from a1 where a.ID_ITEM=a1.ID_ITEM)
and DELIVERY_DATE in (select max(DELIVERY_DATE) from a2 where a.ID_ITEM=a2.ID_ITEM)
```

Comment: Thank you @fahmi. for this case, is it possible to use over (partition by group)?
because I have a lot of join tables and many records.

Comment: what is your dbms? @mae

Comment: i use i navigator 400

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution duplicates the results if there are multiple rows with the same dates and items.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping Is there any other suggestion to be able to detect the same date but the timeline is different?

Comment: @mae Use partitions then